# C# Webbrowser: Define programatically which certificate to use

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, certificate

I've been working on a service that connects to a server which uses digital signature to access the page as a verified user. To be able to connect to the webpage and work with it I'm using the class "WebBrowser" (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netcore-3.1)

Actually, when reaching the webpage this window pop ups to choose one of the possible certificates that I do have in my PC to identify myself:

[image]

To handle this problem, I've been searching on the net and found different potential solution but none of them solve it adequatelly.

To be able to solve the problem, I've included the next code in the class so that I can catch function calls from WebBrowser:

```
    [Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [ComImport]
    public interface UCOMIServiceProvider
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryService(
            [In] ref Guid guidService,
            [In] ref Guid riid,
            [Out] out IntPtr ppvObject);
    }
    [ComImport()]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("79eac9d5-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IWindowForBindingUI
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetWindow(
            [In] ref Guid rguidReason,
            [In, Out] ref IntPtr phwnd);
    }
    [ComImport()]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("79eac9d7-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IHttpSecurity
    {
        //derived from IWindowForBindingUI
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetWindow(
            [In] ref Guid rguidReason,
            [In, Out] ref IntPtr phwnd);
        [PreserveSig]
        int OnSecurityProblem(
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwProblem);
    }
```

And a function to be able to know when there is a problem and try to solve it:

```
            public int OnSecurityProblem(uint dwProblem)
            {
                int dwCertSelection2 = 2;
                IntPtr dwCertSelection = new IntPtr(dwCertSelection2);
                //ignore errors
                //undocumented return code, does not work on IE6
                if (dwProblem == 12044)
                {

                    X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                    X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
                    X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
                    X509Certificate2 x509 = fcollection[2];

                    IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(x509.RawData.Length);
                    Marshal.Copy(x509.RawData, 0, unmanagedPointer, x509.RawData.Length);

                    bool VF_Resultado = WinHttpSetOption(this.myWebBrowser.Handle, 47, unmanagedPointer, x509.RawData.Length);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
                    store.Close();
                    return RPC_E_RETRY;
                }

                return S_OK;
            }
```

To help clarify a bit more:

if (dwProblem == 12044) --> //12044, ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED. It indicates that we need to pass a Certification

bool VF_Resultado = WinHttpSetOption(this.myWebBrowser.Handle, 47, unmanagedPointer, x509.RawData.Length); --> //INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_SELECT_CLIENT_CERT 47, in theory with this function we can indicate the certify we want to use without the need of selecting it.

This code is based in different sources (I've tried both solutions but no luck):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/ssl-in-winhttp

https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/generalinternet/article.php/c3367/Selecting-a-client-certificate.htm

The problem is that this code doesn't do what is intended to do, I've got various doubts to be able to ensure it'll work:

1. Should I use WinHTTP, wininet or another library?
2. When calling the function WinHttpSetOption or InternetSetOption, what should be the handle (1st parameter of the function)?
3. How should I pass the X509 certificate to ensure that WebBrowser understands it and uses it? The code I'm using comes from C++ and I don't know if I'm porting correctly the data, actually I send the raw data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests and reviewing, I reach the conclusion that it's not possible to do this using webBrowser control, this is due to it's mandatory to use this function to pass the certification:

```
WinHttpSetOption(this.myWebBrowser.Handle, WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, dwCertSelection, size)
```

The main problem here is that WinHttpSetOption needs the handler session returned after calling the function "HttpOpenRequest":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/hinternet-handles-in-winhttp#handle-hierarchy

A data that cannot be obtained from C# WebBrowser Object.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.